# Is there any plugin for Visual Studio that can show the method calling stack?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, plugins

I have a legacy application where the method calls go several layers deep:

```
public void A()
{
    B();
}

public void B()
{
    C();
    D();
}

public void C()
{
    E();
}
```

And so on and so forth. Are there any plugins that can show me graphically the methods that are called, so that I can see something like this:

```
A
-> B
    -> C
    -> D
        -> E
```

Comment: Isn't the debugger itself enough for this?

Comment: In design or debug mode?

Comment: `Debug | Windows | Call Stack` ?

Comment: In design mode. I know I can do it in debug mode, but I was wondering if there is anything similar for design mode.

Comment: 'View Call Hierarchy Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T', then 'Calls from/to X'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [Microsoft's CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms979205.aspx)